# SQL Server service broker to pass tables in message or share temporary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

I have a situation where in a stored procedure a lot of select statements are being returned which are final results after a good amount of calculations.

They will execute sequentially, I guess this is taking some time. Trying to optimize the stored procedure, so one plan was to put all the select statements to servicebroker queue as dynamic SQL and execute them.

In this case if we are accessing direct tables then it is fine. As dynamic SQL will run properly but we have temporary tables in the queries which we are unable to pass to service broker.

Is there any way where we can share the temporary tables are pass them by any means.

Comment: guessing isn't a good way to optimize things. You ought to obtain execution plans and *analyze* the parts that are slow. The best way to speed up several statements is to find a way to combine them into a single statement, determine whether it is performing adequately, and to optimize from there. Trying to farm out the work manually is probably just going to add more overheads to the process.

Comment: Truly said, but that part of optimizing the queries is also being done and just trying to save the execution time by asynchronous execution is some thing we are also having in mind, so trying to make it possible.